# Windows 10 not seeing my Ubuntu shares

Tags: 14.04, samba, windows-10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 from 14.04.  I use my Ubuntu PC to share out a 500GB drive /dev/sdb1 which holds my documents and pictures.  All worked fine when my PC was running Windows 10 on 14.04.  I am using the same /etc/samba/smb.conf file on 15.10 as I was using on 14.04.
But apparently a recent Window 10 update has changed the way it sees samba shares.
I am running Samba version 4.1.6, but when I do a "smbstatus"  I see the following error:

Failed to initialize session_global:  NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
Failed to traverse sessions: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/samba/log.winbindd`, please and see if you find the failure I reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1542915?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions where your /dev/sdb1 is mounted.

to check where the /dev/sdb1 is mounted. 
~lsblk

modify permissions

~chmod 711 /*mount point*

maybe even change ownership of the directory you're sharing

~chown user:user /*mount point*

Answer (score 0):

phillip@homeserver:~$ ls -lsblk /dev/sdb1

0 brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Feb  6 20:04 /dev/sdb1

Do mean I should do the following:

sudo chmod 711 /dev/sdb1  ??

I forgot to add that at first this PC only had 1GB of RAM.  I upgraded to 2GB and have another 2GB on order.  It is an old system (ASUS P4P800 mobo)